# Rails not fully compatible with postgresql+postgis geometry data type

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, postgis

I'm using Rails 3.1, and I have tables with the PostGIS `geometry` datatype. These don't seem to be compatible with `rake db:schema:dump` or `rake db:test:clone` and the `rake test:*` tasks. The tables containing this datatype are simply not processed and instantiated by these rake tasks.

Is there any patch or solution for this?

Comment: I have a similar problem with points in my PostGIS database, we think we have narrowed it down to the SchemaDumper methods, possibly with spacial_adapter.  I haven't got a workaround just yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a solution:

First of all, you need a PostgreSQL `template` with PostGIS functions support.

Create a template database:

```
$ psql -U postgres
> CREATE DATABASE template_postgis WITH TEMPLATE=template1 ENCODING='UTF8';
> \c template_postgis;
> CREATE LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Load necessary PostGIS functions into template (I'm using Homebrew, so find the paths to your PostGIS SQL files):

```
$ psql -f /usr/local/share/postgis/postgis.sql template_postgis
$ psql -f /usr/local/share/postgis/spatial_ref_sys.sql template_postgis
```

Set database as template and grant permissions:

```
$ psql -U postgres template_postgis
> UPDATE pg_database SET datistemplate = TRUE WHERE datname = 'template_postgis';
> GRANT ALL ON geometry_columns TO PUBLIC;
> GRANT ALL ON spatial_ref_sys TO PUBLIC;
```

Then, add `gem 'postgis_adapter'` to your `Gemfile` and run `bundle`.
After that add `template: template_postgis` to your `config/database.yml` like this:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  template: template_postgis
  database: postgis_db
```

And - voila! Welcome on board!